# Как добавить поле сортировки в пользовательские поля?

Tags: битрикс

В дополнительных полях, поле получает информацию из инфоблока контакты.
Как добавить возможность выбора порядка отображения(сортировку) на странице? Сейчас в любом случае отображается Зоологический, затем Мичуринский, нужна возможность менять это на странице.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о выводе в шаблон компонента, то можно менять сортировку в файле `result_modifier.php` в папке шаблона компонента - данные прийдут в шаблон в том порядке, в каком Вы их установите там.